# Create a cursor from .cur format bytes?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, cursor

I can find a couple ways to create a cursor in win32 but I need the third, the one I can't find.

The first I can find is to use LoadXXX() to open a file or resource and load the cursor that way.

The second I can find is to use CreateCursor to take the hot-spot points, some data arrays, and make one out of bits.

I want the third way that's between the two: I have an array of bytes that contains a .cur file data.  I want to use that data to make a cursor.  Can this be done?

Comment: That the parameter is a filename?

Comment: Write the .cur file data to a temporary file on disk, then use [`LoadCursorFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648392.aspx).

Comment: Where's the cursor data in memory coming from?  Network?  If you're going to compile it into the product, I assume you'd just put it in the resource section so that the normal APIs work.

Comment: I'm amused that you (or somebody) downvoted the "write it to file" solution as unprofessional and unacceptable, and you (or somebody) downvoted my "roll your own from the docs" solution.  In programming there's always another way, maybe, but I don't think there's another way in this case that's too different from those two approaches.

Comment: I downvoted both.  I'm tired of people providing answers just for points (you) and I always downvote bad advice (write to file).  Having mentioned CreateCursor in the question one would expect that people shouldn't find it necessary to quote the documentation on it at me, but you did.  You will find that point whoring like that works here at SO but I don't have to be happy about it.  I downvoted both because I thought they were both dumb responses to the question.  I wish I could downvote twice when you start crying about it.

Comment: So, I guess it's clear here that you really are just a jerk. Would you be happier with the simpler answer that *doesn't* try to propose a workaround? "No, this can't be done. There's no API for that." Or would you downvote *that* as well, claiming it's "not helpful" or some such something? I oppose point whoring just as much as you, and I will vote down answers that are genuinely wrong, but you've really got to work on matching your question writing abilities to your expectations for answers. Or maybe just the negative attitude in general.

Comment: @Cody - OK, I'll be sure to mention the fact that I'm not interested in completely absurd answers next time.  Would that have kept you from suggesting that I write a file to disk just so I can read it back into memory again?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Can't be done.  Best not to waste time trying.  I was only trying to avoid having to convert a bunch of .cur files to something that sensible libraries support.  Thought I'd use the HCURSOR constructor for QCursor, and I could, but it's just not worth the f'n bother trying to work around the worse imaginable API when I can just use PNG files or something.

Answer (score 3):

As I more briefly posted in a comment, I think the easiest and most sensible way is to just write the binary data stored in the array out to a temporary .CUR file on disk, and then use the [`LoadCursorFromFile` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648392.aspx) to read that .CUR file. You can then remove the temporary file. There's no reason to go hunting for complicated solutions when simpler ones will do.

That being said, if you really need a way to do this, you might consider doing something similar to what the .NET Framework team did to load a cursor object from a memory stream. This takes advantage of the [similarity between cursors and icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx).

Use the [`OleCreatePictureIndirect` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694511.aspx) to create a new uninitialized [`IPicture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, which you then initialize from your array of bytes in memory via the [`IPersistStream::Load` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680568.aspx). Once you've done that, just use the [`CopyImage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648031.aspx) to create a cursor from the loaded image.

Comment: This is a professional product, such a solution is not at all acceptable.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: What does it being a "professional product have to do with anything? This is a perfectly plausible solution to do what you're asking. In fact, it IS used in a professional product. What *specifically* about it do you think is unprofessional and "unacceptable"? If you're going to downvote perfectly valid answers because they don't meet your arbitrarily high standards, you need to include a *detailed* description of those in the question.

Comment: Which product?  Would be nice to know who's software to avoid.

Comment: @Noah: It's unclear if you read the entire answer, or just the first paragraph. The reason I chose to post an answer (rather than just the comment) is to add the second and third paragraphs: "That being said, if you really need a way to do this, you might consider doing something similar to what the .NET Framework team did". I don't know if you're just trying to arrogantly decry the .NET Framework as being "not a professional product", or if you just can't be bothered to take the time to read an entire answer before downvoting it.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to CreateCursor() are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648385(VS.85).aspx

```
HCURSOR WINAPI CreateCursor(
  __in_opt  HINSTANCE hInst,
  __in      int xHotSpot,
  __in      int yHotSpot,
  __in      int nWidth,
  __in      int nHeight,
  __in      const VOID *pvANDPlane,
  __in      const VOID *pvXORPlane
);
```

The .cur file format is documented on Wikipedia here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#Legacy_format

You can get all the arguments to CreateCursor() out of that icon file header; I think the pointer to the image data probably has a bitmap for the and plane directly followed by a bitmap for the xor plane.

Comment: I believe I did mention CreateCursor in my question.  I know I can research and write my own reader.  You can ALWAYS write your own.  I'm looking for an API solution.

Comment: You did mention CreateCursor in your question.  There's not an API solution.  Up to you whether you consider something in between helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst looking for the answer to this, I stumbled across CreateIconIndirect, which "Creates an icon or cursor from an ICONINFO structure" that specifies a bitmap handle (HBITMAP) for the cursor image (so you can use the Win32 API bitmap routines to prepare the cursor):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createiconindirect

```
HICON CreateIconIndirect(
    PICONINFO piconinfo
);
```

Though its return type is HICON, the documentation says it returns an icon or cursor.

The ICONINFO structure has a boolean fIcon member to determine whether it is an icon (TRUE) or a cursor (FALSE):

```
typedef struct _ICONINFO {
    BOOL    fIcon;
    DWORD   xHotspot;
    DWORD   yHotspot;
    HBITMAP hbmMask;
    HBITMAP hbmColor;
} ICONINFO;
```

I've not yet used this in my program and realise this is a really old question, but hopefully it will point anyone else that is trying to do this in the right direction.